# zshrc file contains two paths

Tags: terminal, path, zshrc

I was recently trying to add a utility called Cask to Homebrew and the installation kept failing because due to 2 errors:

1. `Error: Your CLT does not support macOS 11.`
2. `Error: An exception occurred within a child process:`

There was a third error that was suggesting that I modify the path with  `echo export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"`

Now my .zshrc file shows 2 `$PATH`.

Is this going to cause a problem?

Thank you